# How can I make dropbox display an icon in Gnome Shell?

Tags: gnome, dropbox

There's no icon of dropbox in the gnome-shell's tray (bottom-right corner). There's just text. I tried different icon themes but still it's missing. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Dropbox Screenshot]

Answer (score 6):

You don't say which gnome-shell ypu are using. For me works (sort of) by installing the extension [*TopIcons*](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/) and [*AppIndicator and KStatusNotifierItem Support*](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/615/appindicator-support/) (this one with these settings):

[image: AppIndicatorSettings]

(Sometimes the Dropbox icon appears in the list, sometimes no). The result is this:

[image: Dropbox icon in panel]

From time to time, the Dropbox icon disappears after a resume (but Dropbox is still working). Issuing

```
dropbox stop
dropbox start
```

make the icon reappear. [I reported the bug](https://github.com/rgcjonas/gnome-shell-extension-appindicator/issues/40).

Comment: Seems to do the trick with CentOS 7\RHEL 7 versions which use Gnome 3! Thanks :)

Comment: I didn't have to install the indicator app, just TopIcons-Plus and manually restart dropbox. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

How did you install dropbox?

The following should work fine (including in gnome-shell):

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox
```

When asked to install dropbox from the original location choose not to. After installation it will ask for your login details.
You can check the process with this command:

```
ps ax|grep dropbox
```

You can start it manually (from a terminal) with:

```
dropbox start
```

Comment: it is started, works good and installed just like you advice..

Comment: try restarting nautilus (in a terminal): nautilus -q && nautilus&